# Get a pointer to BSTR from a vector<BSTR>

Tags: c++, com

I want to call a COM method which expects a BSTR array and separate parameter specifying the size of the array, it then populates the array. Will the following work properly - it compiles but I want to be sure about the `&*` since I know sys-strings are generally waiting to trip me up at every opportunity!

```
vector<BSTR> strings(5);
BSTR *pStrings = &*strings.begin();

pComInterface->method(strings.size(),pStrings);
```

Comment: provided your description of the method is correct, it's okay, although needlessly verbose. just do `p->m( strings.size(), &strings[0] )`.

Comment: @Alf `&strings[0]` causes undefined behaviour if the vector is empty (which it isn't in this case of course, but my point is that if using `&vec[0]` in general you need to check the vector is not empty first)

Comment: Do you have the (M)IDL or exact definition of the interface? This is not enough for a definitive answer.

Comment: @MattMcNabb - base COM can marshal arrays of things fine if the IDL is carefully written, w/o resorting to IMarshal. Automation (which is a superset or subset depending on the way you see it) clients do not support the whole COM possibilities (and BSTR smells like automation :-)

Comment: @SimonMourier you're right - deleted my comment now. For example, `[in] long cElems, [in, size_is(cElems)] BSTR *bs`

Comment: It seems to me that using BSTR even for a non-Automation application is OK, as it self-documents how the string memory should be allocated and freed

Comment: @MattMcNabb - absolutely, but it was not designed for this, the B standing for "Basic" (VB/VBA originally and then VBScript, JScript, ...). The cool thing with Automation types like BSTR is they don't need IDL definition, specific proxies and stubs, even for non Automation uses (hence heavily used in delphi, matlab, even C++, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the COM interface method receives a std::size_t (or equivalent) and a BSTR*, you probably should use std::vector::data() instead of dereferencing an iterator:

```
pComInterface->method(strings.size(), strings.data());
```

Comment: re "you probably should use std::vector::data()", it has the disadvantage that it's C++11, and I fail to see any advantage. what is the basis for this assertion.

Comment: It has the advantage that it doesn't instantiate an iterator instance (although for a vector, the iterator instantiation cost should probably be trivial). It also looks cleaner (the &*<iterator> construct breaks Demeter's law). `std::vector::data` was created exactly for getting the address of the beginning of the allocated block - that's why I suggested it. Alternately, you can use `&front()` as well.

Comment: I think @utnapistim's answer is correct but _only_ for C++11. Possibly the answer should be edited (or another submitted) clarifying.

Comment: @utnapistim: re "It has the advantage that it doesn't instantiate an iterator instance", the idiomatic expression `&s[0]` doesn't instantiate any iterator instance. So that imagined relative efficiency edge is not an advantage: it doesn't exist. It sounds very much like a premature optimization.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, I was comparing to the construct in the OP's question, regarding `&*strings.begin();`, which _does_ instantiate an iterator. I also mentioned the reason for the replacement to be respecting Demeter's Law (design principle) not speed (optimization). For optimization purposes, I too consider such a change premature (at least until you measure it).